# Not able to access Marklogic DHF, Getting 8010 access error

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am just trying to setup Marklogic DHF using the quick start guide and as soon as I enter the user/name password at localhost:8080 and hit enter, I got the below error.

```
2023-11-11 23:20:40.029 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-11-11 23:20:41.219 [main] INFO  c.marklogic.hub.central.Application - Started Application in 14.615 seconds (JVM running for 15.403)
2023-11-11 23:20:48.885 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl - Could not find the datahubConfig.json file. Logging the cause for the failure
2023-11-11 23:20:48.887 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl - java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8010
2023-11-11 23:20:49.357 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.m.a.DefaultAppConfigFactory - App host: localhost
2023-11-11 23:20:49.358 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.m.a.DefaultAppConfigFactory - REST admin username: admin
2023-11-11 23:20:49.360 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.m.a.DefaultAppConfigFactory - App Services username: admin
2023-11-11 23:20:49.375 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.m.m.a.DefaultAdminConfigFactory - Admin interface host: localhost
2023-11-11 23:20:49.378 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.m.m.a.DefaultAdminConfigFactory - Admin interface username: admin
2023-11-11 23:20:49.403 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.m.mgmt.DefaultManageConfigFactory - Manage host: localhost
2023-11-11 23:20:49.405 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.m.mgmt.DefaultManageConfigFactory - Manage username: admin
2023-11-11 23:20:49.407 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.m.mgmt.DefaultManageConfigFactory - Manage user with security role: admin
2023-11-11 23:20:49.728 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.marklogic.mgmt.ManageClient - Initializing ManageClient with manage config of: [ManageConfig host: localhost, port: 8002, username: admin, security username: admin]
2023-11-11 23:20:49.827 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.marklogic.mgmt.ManageClient - Initializing ManageClient with manage config of: [ManageConfig host: localhost, port: 8002, username: admin, security username: admin]
2023-11-11 23:20:51.941 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8010
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:704)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:697)
```

**Using:**

DHF version 6

Marklogic version 10.0-10.2

Java: 1.8

Could you please help me, not sure what exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just installed the DHF WAR and trying to access it through Admin credentials. For DHF we have specific role 'hub-central-developer' by which you can get access to Data Hub Central. Please follow the https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/6.0/projects/create-project-hubcentral.html guidelines to initialize the DHF.